# How to use es6 classes in *.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webpack

Added config files to the project (`packege.json` &`webpack.config.json`), added `babel`. At the moment it turns out like this: There is a directory `/ Scripts / build` &`Scripts / es6 (/main.js)`. When the `npm run build` command is run, everything builds ok (from the`main.js` file as indicated in the `entry` section of the`webpack.config.json` file), the `bundle.js` file is created in the`/ Scripts / build directory`. In the above, there are no problems and everything is as it should. Now I want to use the `js` classes (their methods and properties) in the views (`* .cshtml`). How do i do this? Or need a different approach? If I write `js` code in`main.js`, then I build it, then the code fulfills. But how do I make a function and run it (for example, by clicking a button)?

packege.json:

```
{
  "name": "SensorDashboard",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --mode='development' -p"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./Scripts/es6/main.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts/build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    // IMPORTANT NOTE: If you are using Webpack 2 or above, replace "loaders" with "rules"
    module: {
        rules: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    }
}
```

main.js:

```
import { Map, MyClass } from './Map';

(function () {
    window.test_func = function () {
        let cl = new MyClass();
        cl.send("asd qweqwe");
    };
})();
```

MyClass:

```
export class MyClass {
    send(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}
```

then i runing command: `npm run build`, and a file was created (`/Script/build/bundle.js`)

then i try to use in `*.cshtml`:

```
@{Layout = null;}
...
<script src="~/Scripts/build/bundle.js"></script>
...
<div>....</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
        test_func(); //this work

        let m = new MyClass(); //this don`t work (MyClass is not defined)
        m.send("asd");
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think should be as simple as loading the script in your .cshtml file with your standard script tag at the bottom of the file which would look something like this:

```
@section Scripts { 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/build/main.js")"></script>

}
```

(possibly without the @Url.Content though I'm not 100% sure offhand)

You could then call a function by doing something like the following example, there are a few ways and probably depends on what your class looks like in your main.js:

```
@section Scripts { 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/build/main.js")"></script>

    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function(){
            let someClass = new Class();
            someClass.DoSomething();

        }
}
```

Let me know if I've misunderstood the question.

Edit:

Okay, sorry I did misunderstand.

Have a look at this [link](https://itnext.io/calling-a-es6-webpacked-class-from-outside-js-scope-f36dc77ea130) and see if it helps you? It looks like exactly what you need.

It has instructions on how to configure webpack to allow calling externally.

Looks as simple as adding these two lines to your output:

`libraryTarget: 'var',
library: 'EntryPoint'`

Where EntryPoint is the Name you want for the module .

So:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'MyModule'
  },
```

And that should allow you to just call

`EntryPoint.send("asd qweqwe");`

Comment: I added `<script src ="~/Scripts/build/ bundle.js"></script>`. After I write: `$ (document) .ready (function () {let m = new MyClass (); m.send (" asd ");});` and I see the error `MyClass is not defined`, but if I write `in main.js`: `window.test_func = function () {let cl = new MyClass (); cl.send ("asd qweqwe");};` I run npm run build and use `test_func ()` - then everything is ok

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц When you open your dev tools, and look at the network tab, does it show that script file as being loaded correctly or does it have a 404 error code?

Comment: status code 304 (green). window.test_func works under the same conditions (as I understand it is a static variable).

Comment: maybe add configs to the question, and how am I trying to define classes?

Comment: Yeah, I think how it's defined might help.

Comment: does not work. `console.log (EntryPoint)` displays the module. But `EntryPoint.send ()` does not work (error). And how can I create an instance of the class this way?